# Can we register a web application to receive notifications from Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to create a web application which receives notification from Azure Notification Hub.

Everywhere I only see mobile devices registering for notifications sent from back-end.

I want this web application to be used in browser and receives notification from Azure Notification Hub sent from back-end.

Thanks

Comment: Has anything changed here? Are services buses still the right component to achieve notifications in a web app? Maybe relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services?toc=%2fazure%2fservice-bus-messaging%2ftoc.json

Comment: Now is possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/browser-push

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope.

[Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-services/jj927170(v=azure.100)) are exclusively for push notifications for mobile platforms.

If you want a code to receive a notification you shall take a look at [Azure Service Bus Queues, Topics and Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions). Then decide which of all to use.

It is mentioned in [Notification Hubs FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq) *(Do you support text message, email, or web notifications?)* that you can do it by using [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) on top of Notification Hubs :

> Customers can implement this feature using SignalR on top of the supported server-side platforms.

Comment: Can't i use azure mobile services for sending push notification to web application?

Comment: `push notifications` are for mobile platforms (say iOS, Windows Phone, Android, etc.). They are not for server platforms (say Web Server of any kind). And ServiceBus API has a nice "push"-imitating form, which allows you in your server code to "subscribe" for a message: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/OnMessage-programing-model-58451157

Comment: Has anything changed here? Are services buses still the right component to achieve notifications in a web app? Maybe relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services?toc=%2fazure%2fservice-bus-messaging%2ftoc.json

Comment: nothing with respect to Azure Notification Hubs or the purpose of the mobile vendors push notifications. "Web notifications" or "desktop notifications" are fundamentally different concept (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification or https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification) and you cannot use push notification service for desktop notifications.

Comment: @astaykov Why did you deleted my edit? I thought it was useful to know it's a planned feature!
thanks

Comment: because this is not my statement, and because my answer is from 2013. You are free to contribute a new answer, properly receive votes for it, etc.
In addition, my personal opinion is, that developer should know what are they doing. Push Notification Services (PNS) are not for Web Sites. This is feature of the mobile OS Vendors. SignalR is what a web developer should really be using for websites. And there is currently Azure SignalR service. 
Last but not least - I would not rely on "planned" features to give people hope ;)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in previous answers Azure's Notification Hubs only work for mobile devices because behind the scenes it interacts with the various mobile platforms' push notification services such as the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS).  It is not sending the notifications directly to the client.  Since there are no push notification services for websites you need another technology.

Azure offers Service Bus Queues which would work, but it also offers [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr) which is probably the best solution in your case, and in fact the one I plan to use for a web frontend I am building for my service.  SignalR handles all the low level connection details for you, i.e. it takes care of using the optimal protocol for the browser you are running in which is no mean task!  It's fast, scalable and surprisingly easy to implement.

Comment: The cheapest way is to use this nuget https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp